# understanding a step in proof of strong approximation for $SL_2$

Tags: number-theory, topological-groups, adeles

Let $k$ be a global field and $k_v$ denote its completion at a place $v$.

Let $Z$ be the closure of $SL_2(k)$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{A})$; $Z$ is a subgroup.  Assume $Z$ contains $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_v)$ for each place $v$. Why does that mean $Z$ contains the *infinite* product
$\prod_v SL_2(\mathcal{O}_v)$? I think it has to do with $Z$ being topologically closed and the topology adele groups  but I think I'm missing the simple topological reason.

Below is the full argument given here [http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248BPage/handouts/strongapprox.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/248BPage/handouts/strongapprox.pdf) and
and I get all the other parts.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of $SL_2(\Bbb{A}_k)$, its topology:

The elements $(a_v)\in \prod_v SL_2(k_v)$ such that $a_v\in SL_2(O_v)$ for all but finitely many $v$.

$x^{(n)} \to x$ if all the $x^{(n)}_{v_j}$ are in $SL_2(O_{v_j})$ for $j$ large enough and $x^{(n)}_v\to x_v$ (in the norm of $k_v^{2\times 2}$) for all $v$.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that the condition $x_v^{(n)} \to x_v$ does not require it to converge uniformly in $v$ if that makes sense. So if $x=(x_{v_j}) \in \prod SL_2(\mathbb{A})$ then the sequence $(x_{v_1}, 1, 1 ..), \ (x_{v_1}, x_{v_2}, 1 ..), \ (x_{v_1}, x_{v_2}, x_{v_3}, 1 ..) $ converges to $x$